# Can Neo4j automatically detect relationships between uploaded entities without a separate file containing only relationships?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Is it possible for Neo4j to detect relationships between entities without uploading a file which containing only relationships?

When I use Neo4j, first I create nodes by upload files that contain the entities, and then create the relationship among the nodes by a file (or files) that defines the relationships between the entities. Would it be possible to have Neo4j detect the relationships without uploading the relationship file(s)? As an example, we have two entities that have already been indexed and uploaded as follows:
A including: A.ID, A.Year, A.Name
B including: B.ID, B.Year, B.Name
Would it be possible to detect a relationship between A and B based on A.ID=B.ID AND A.Year<=B.Year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

You can do something like this:

```
MATCH (a:Foo), (b:Foo)
WHERE a <> b AND a.ID = b.ID AND (a.Year < b.Year OR (a.Year = b.Year AND id(a) < id(b)))
CREATE (a)-[:BAR]->(b)
```

Notes:

1. To speed up this query, you should consider creating either an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/#indexes-drop-indexes) or [uniqueness constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/) on `:Foo(ID)`.
2. To avoid creating a relationship from a `Foo` node to itself, we specify the `a <> b` condition.
3. The `a.Year <= b.Year` condition allows equal `Year` values, so the same pair of `Foo` nodes can be matched twice (as a/b, and as b/a). So we specify the `(a.Year = b.Year AND ID(a) < ID(b))` condition to avoid creating 2 relationships between the same pair of nodes in opposite directions. The [id](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-id) function returns the native ID, not your `ID` property.

###### Final tweak

While the above query works, we don't actually need to specify the `a <> b` condition as stated in Note #2, since the code mentioned in Note #3 is sufficient to enforce that condition. So, you can omit `a <> b AND`  from the query.

Comment: The code is working but there is an issue with the ID. When I use:

...AND a.ID < b.ID AND a.Year <= b.Year, or

...AND a.ID > b.ID AND a.Year <= b.Year,

it returned the relationships, But when I use:

...AND a.ID = b.ID AND a.Year <= b.Year,

it doesn't detect any relationship and I can see identical IDs on a and b.

Note: I read the data from CSV and the type of IDs is string.

Comment: In my testing, I do not see that issue. However, I do see that my original query could still create 2 relationships between the same pair of nodes, in opposite directions. That was because my query was testing for existing relationships *before* creating any relationships. I have modified my query to fix that (see my updated note #3.

Comment: For now forget about the relationship. The type of a.ID and b.ID is string. The issue is = operator doesn't work on ID, e.g. this code doesn't work:

MATCH (a:foo), (b:foo)

WHERE a.ID=b.ID

RETURN a.ID

But when I use a.ID<b.ID or a.ID>b.ID it returns values.

Comment: No, string equality comparisons do work. For example, this query returns true: `RETURN "abc" = "abc"`. The same applies for node string property comparisons. Please show the a.ID and b.ID values for which you are having problems. It is possible that the strings actually have different encodings but look the same, or there can be weird characters like [zero-width spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)

Comment: something like this: 00914Y,
01325V,
01409B,
01586R,
30246,
30345,
30378,
30405,

Comment: I noticed what was the issue, your code working perfectly. The issue was about constraints and the method of reading CSV. Because the constraint was a unique key, lots of data didn't store as nodes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a really cool way of doing that, it's called node-similarity and it works by putting relevant attributes of the nodes into a feature vector and then running a k-nearest-neighbours or (approximate kNN) algorithm on top of the data which will create a top-k similar (e.g. top-5) network out of the data.

See here:

https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/similarity/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1a3b5x1BOU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBc__rhm6AY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fh-alMQ7h_U

Comment: I am not sure node-similarity can help me in this context. i have two types of nodes with code: BP343, In one type, this code is part of a combined key and in another one this code is a unique key. What I want is to get the relationship from the combined key but apply them or show them on the unique key, do you think it is possible?

Comment: Something like this code is possible? : MATCH (a:a_Key), (b:b_Key), (a_Ukey:a_UniqueKey), (b_UKey:b_UniqueKey)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((a_Ukey)-[:foo}]-(b_UKey)) AND a.a_Key = b.b_Key AND a.Year <= b.Year AND b.Year='2022' AND b_UKey='BP343'
CREATE (a_Ukey)-[:foo]->(b_UKey)
Return *;

Answer (score 0):

To be able to include all the IDs, I should make the constraint a combination of three properties, something like this:

CREATE CONSTRAINT a_Key FOR (a:a) REQUIRE (a.Prog, a.ID, a.Year) IS UNIQUE;

and the same for b. but when I applied the relationship as explained in the post but for a specific b.ID = BP343, I saw multiple similar nodes in the final graph output as below, because their combination keys are different:

[BP343 is a sample id from b and green items are ID from a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSXK7.png)

What I need is just one blue node because they have similar ID in the shape. How is it possible?